# How to give a QMenuBar button an action?

Tags: python, qt, qt4, pyqt, pyqt4

I develop a GUI using PyQt/Qt4/QtDesigner. It includes a MenuBar with buttons. For example,`File` drops down to show `Exit`. I am struggling to understand how to add an action to these buttons. Is it the same as with QPushButtons?

Comment: Really nice [tutorial](http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt4/menusandtoolbars/) about menus and toolbars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to add anything.  Menu items emit a `triggered()` signal when they are triggered.  Qt has an automatic slot for this--in C++, in `MainGui.h` you would have

```
class MainGui
{
   ...
   private slots:
      void on_actionExit_triggered(); //For command Exit
      void on_actionSave_Data_triggered(); //For command Save Data
};
```

And then you just write the callback as you see fit.  I presume the structure is very similar in Python.

Edit: Here's the .cpp file:

```
void MainGui::on_actionExit_triggered()
{
   //Do whatever you like here
}
```

Comment: Within the slot I could call a function? Again I apologize for my low level of understanding of Qt, is there a way I could do this in Python?

Comment: Showing C++ code in a question about Python is a bit unusual, even if translating from Qt to PyQt is really simple. I added an answer in Python.

Comment: @Trilarion I understand, but I think the required concept transcends the particular language, and since C++ is the original language of Qt it seems ok to me to post this.

Answer (score -1):

It's almost the same as with `QPushButtons`. Buttons get clicked, menu actions get triggered. However you can simply connect to the corresponding slot.

Here is a simply example for an exit functionality:

```
class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        # menu bar
        self.menu_bar = QtGui.QMenuBar(self)

        # file menu
        self.menu_file = QtGui.QMenu(self.menu_bar)
        self.menu_file.setTitle('File')
        self.menu_bar.addAction(self.menu_file.menuAction())

        # exit action
        self.menu_action_exit = QtGui.QAction(self)
        self.menu_action_exit.setText("Exit")
        self.menu_action_exit.triggered.connect(self.close)
```

Comment: Doesn't work, menu_action_exit is never added to the menu.